# I suffered with my wife?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, semantic-roles

I referred to many dictionaries and found that the verb **suffer**
is not followed by the preposition **with**

I have found the following sentences.

> *1. I suffered from fever.*
>
> *2. One has to suffer for one's  sins.*
>
> *3. You have to  suffer in the end.*

But I found a website which says suffer can be followed by the preposition with.

> 1. I **suffered with** my wife  due to some financial problems.
> 2. I **suffer with** gout.

Are the sentences  grammatically  correct  and acceptable to  native speakers?

I herewith attach the [link](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-correct-suffer-with-or-suffer-from) for your kind perusal.

Comment: *Suffered with my wife* is a lot different in meaning to *Suffered my wife*

Comment: @smoke.I think it means  I suffered along with my wife

Comment: Exactly, which is why the *with* is very important in the sentence - you asked about the use of *with*. Without *with* it means something else entirely.

Comment: @smoke.What is your opinion about my question being downvoted.Is there not a point  in my asking?

Comment: I couldn't say, I don't know why it was downvoted. I don't see anything wrong with it, but I'm a relative newbie here at ELL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the use of *suffer with* fits in the context when you want to add someone with you.

An example there is -

> *“Heidi suffered with her grandpa when they ran low on food and firewood during the cold winter months.”*

To understand it better...think like this

> *“Heidi suffered (with her grandpa) when (they) ran low on food and firewood during the cold winter months.”*

But still, I'd prefer an alternate way to tell the same ...

> *My wife and I suffered from financial crises.*

To answer, native speakers may not find it idiomatic.

Comment: the "i suffer with gout" is good though

Comment: @WendyG.I would like to know whether  the sentences are acceptable to native speakers.But I do not know why it was downvoted?